# Html/Javascript - How to make an html link display a url, and have it actually be redirected to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, hyperlink

I have an html page, and I need a link to show that the user would be going to 'example.html', when really, the link goes to 'javascipt:ajaxLoad(example.html);'.

I tried this:

```
<a href="example" onclick="javascipt:ajaxLoad(example.html);">Example</a>
```

But it didn't work. Any help? I already asked the webmasters stackexchange, and they told me that this would be a javascript programming question. Not an html question.

Comment: your example says `javascipt` instead of `javascript`. Where do you want it to show 'example.html'?

Comment: http://www.bradino.com/javascript/onclick-return-false/ Like Marc b said onclick=...ajaxLoad(...); return false;

Comment: @alquatoun — that doesn't matter, it is a label with no associated loop. It is utterly meaningless, so the spelling is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="example.html" onclick="ajaxLoad(this.href); return false;">Example</a>
```

By returning false you prevent the default action. And this way the links will still work when javascript is disabled, but then you don't get the AJAX functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Just point the href at the actual file. The javascript onclick will take precedence - as long as you take care to disable the actual click effect by doing a "return false" or similar, the status bar will show 'example.html' and not the javascript url.

As well, note that it should be `javascript:...` (you're missing an `r`). The `onwhatever` attributes are already assumed to be javascript, so you could just say `onclick="ajaxLoad(...)` anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Look, I'm not sure if I got exactly what you're asking about here, but the following fix often works with me. Just change the double-quotes to single-quotes, and put double-quotes around the example.html part

```
<a href="example" onclick='javascipt:ajaxLoad("example.html");'>Example</a>
```